# How to auto complete remote path with scp on Powershell?

Tags: powershell

On zsh it can be easily auto completion by:

```
scp file user@hostname:/some/pa<tab>
```

How to make it works for Powershell on Windows10?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to implement an [argument completer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/register-argumentcompleter?view=powershell-7.1) for the SCP command. I didn't find any working implementation, you may have a better luck.

As an example, here's a gist implementing hostname autocomplete for both SSH and SCP: https://gist.github.com/backerman/2c91d31d7a805460f93fe10bdfa0ffb0